# ld: Invalid value (Producer: 'LLVM13.0.0-rust-1.57.0-nightly' Reader: 'LLVM APPLE_1_1300.0.29.3_0') for architecture arm64

Tags: swift, rust, clang, cocoapods, llvm

Trying to install and work with [zkgroup](https://github.com/signalapp/zkgroup).
Build, run for specific iOS device working fine.

But generic archiving is not working.

Error text:
`ld: Invalid value (Producer: 'LLVM13.0.0-rust-1.57.0-nightly' Reader: 'LLVM APPLE_1_1300.0.29.3_0') for architecture arm64`

Rust toolchain:

```
installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-2021-06-08-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-2021-09-16-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-2021-09-19-x86_64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-ios
aarch64-apple-ios-sim
x86_64-apple-darwin
x86_64-apple-ios

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-2021-09-16-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.57.0-nightly (2c7bc5e33 2021-09-15)
```

Any insight?

Comment: Have you been able to sort this out? I'm running into a similar issue with `ld: Invalid value (Producer: 'LLVM13.0.0-rust-1.57.0-stable' Reader: 'LLVM APPLE_1_1300.0.29.30_0') for architecture arm64`

Comment: I am also running into this problem when trying to archive an iOS app that links against a static library written in Rust.

Comment: This feels like the same cause as discussed in this [question and answer pair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63434546/558006).  In this case, the solution would seem to be to get cargo to use the Apple Developer LLVM rather than the rust-provided LLVM, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56399256/558006).  I am going to dive into learning about how to specify the LLVM used by the rust compiler and see if I can expand this comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to this problem turns out to be deceptively simple: set the Xcode build setting "Enable Bitcode" to "No", as in this image:
[image: Xcode build settings]
(I figured this out by first discovering that command-line archive builds did not have this problem, and then comparing their log with the in-Xcode build log. The in-XCode build was doing bitcode-verify operations, which reminded me that the [Rust cargo-lipo](https://github.com/TimNN/cargo-lipo) README talks about turning this setting off to avoid this LLVM incompatibility.)

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with this error while using the [isar](https://pub.dev/packages/isar) package in Flutter. The problem was with isar_flutter_libs 2.5.0.

## Solution

1. Delete pubspec.lock and podfile.lock
2. Downgrade all isar libs to 2.4.0
3. In the terminal, run dart pub remove isar_flutter_libs
4. flutter pub get
5. pod update